# django trunk AuthContextProcessorTests test_session_not_accessed fails

Tags: django

I am using the trunk version of django in a project and when I run my unit tests, I get

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_session_not_accessed         (django.contrib.auth.tests.context_processors.AuthContextProcessorTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./../django-trunk/django/contrib/auth/tests/context_processors.py", line 31, in test_session_not_accessed
self.assertContains(response, "Session not accessed")
  File "./../django-trunk/django/test/testcases.py", line 524, in assertContains
msg_prefix + "Couldn't find '%s' in response" % text)
AssertionError: Couldn't find 'Session not accessed' in response
```

Based on commit 1964aac273 on https://github.com/django/django

I am not sure what I need in order to pass this test.

Comment: you should move this question to the django user or dev list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in django.

Reference - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16366